# Azure custom vision choose training time

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-custom-vision

i'm using API to load my data and make prediction. I have seen documentation to train model using code (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Custom-Vision-Service/python-tutorial) but I can't figure how to chose training time of my model using the API?

edit: curently i'm importing data using code, training model using azure portal, and making prediction with code

edit2: more info about global process
i'm using Azure congitive service to do an image classification task, multiclass (images can belong to only 1 label).

Comment: Please elaborate on the point when you say "how to chose training time of my model using the API" What do you want to achieve it here...

Comment: In the tutorial in the part "Train the classifier and publish" the author train his classifier. But in azure portal we can choose to train the classifier from 1 hours to 24 hours (and we pay depending the training time). I want to be able to choose to train my classifier for, for example, 3hours

Comment: Sure let me take a look and get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically to queue project for training, you have to use below API :

```
POST {Endpoint}/customvision/v3.0/training/projects/{projectId}/train?trainingType={trainingType}&reservedBudgetInHours={reservedBudgetInHours}&forceTrain={forceTrain}&notificationEmailAddress={notificationEmailAddress}
```

trainingType should be advanced in case if you want to give hours for computing and you have to provide reservedBudgetInHours in number for computing hours.

**`trainingType string The type of training to use to train the project (default: Regular).`**

**`reservedBudgetInHours    The number of hours reserved as budget for training (if applicable).`**

Additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/customvisiontraining/trainproject/trainproject

If you are looking for a way to do it using SDK , then you have to use following method:

```
train_project(project_id, training_type=None, reserved_budget_in_hours=0, force_train=False, notification_email_address=None, custom_headers=None, raw=False, **operation_config)
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-customvision/azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.training.custom_vision_training_client.customvisiontrainingclient?view=azure-python#train-project-project-id--training-type-none--reserved-budget-in-hours-0--force-train-false--notification-email-address-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-

Hope it helps.